# Coincidiendo una expresión regular al final de una cadena en Python 2.7.13

Tags: python, python-2.7, regex

Tengo la siguiente cadena:

```
fo = "b---00b<do:YYYY>tftt_<fd>-<fd><ct><ct:MM>mmm.pdf"
```

Y sólo quiero obtener `mmm.pdf`.

Cuando intento:

```
match = re.search(r'(>.*?\.pdf)', fo)

for g in match.groups():
    print g
```

Obtengo:

```
>tftt_<fd>-<fd><ct><ct:MM>mmm.pdf
```

Pensé que el símbolo `?` haría que la búsqueda se detuviera en `>`, pero el patrón `(>.*\.pdf)` me da el mismo resultado.
¿Cuál es la expresión regular correcta para obtener `mmm.pdf`?

`mmm.pdf` puede ser `abcs.pdf`, `qwerty123.pdf`, etc. And `fo` siempre tiene el formato:

```
fo = "someOptionalstring<otherstring>anotherOptionalString<string>optionalstring<string>mmm.pdf"
```

La alternancia entre `strings` (pueden ser vacías) y `<strings>` (no vacías) puede estar en cualquier cantidad.
Pude hallar expresiones regulares para extraer las cadenas entre `<>`, pero no la cadena que quiero al final.

Podría usar un algoritmo usando `endswith()` y buscando el último caracter `>`, pero quiero intentar usar expresiones regulares por motivos de aprendizaje.

**Edit:** Para quienes están aprendiendo: olvidé mencionar que hay que importar el módulo `re`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*?` es simplemente un cuantificador "no ambicioso", con la expresión  `>.*\.pdf` lo que dices en realidad es algo así:

> "Busca una subcadena  que empiece con el carácter `>`, seguido de la **mínima cantidad posible de caracteres**  y que termine con `.pdf`"

Si eliminas `?`  entonces el cuantificador es avaricioso:

> "Busca una subcadena  que empiece con el carácter `>`, seguido de la **máxima cantidad posible de caracteres** y  que termine con`.pdf`"

Con un ejemplo a lo mejor se ve más claro:

```
>>> import re

>>> fo = ">aaa.pdf>mmm.pdf"

>>> re.search(r"(>.*?\.pdf)", fo).group()
'>aaa.pdf'

>>> re.search(r"(>.*\.pdf)", fo).group()
'>aaa.pdf>mmm.pdf'
```

En tu caso no hay diferencia porque la única coincidencia posible  es `>tftt_<fd>-<fd><ct><ct:MM>mmm.pdf` en ambos casos, desde la primera aparición de `>` hasta que encuentra `.pdf`, ya que solo hay una subcadena `.pdf` en la cadena

Una posibilidad es simplemente usar la expresión `[^>]+.pdf$`:

- **`[^>]+`** -> Uno o más caracteres que no sean `>`
- **`$`** -> Indica el final de la cadena, esto hace que la coincidencia solo pueda estar al final, por ejemplo `<mmm.pdf>foo` no sería una coincidencia.

---

```
import re 


regex = re.compile(r"[^>]+.pdf$")

fo = "b---00b<do:YYYY>tftt_<fd>-<fd><ct><ct:MM>mmm.pdf"

match = regex.search(fo)
print(match.group())
```

---

Hay que tener en cuenta que la búsqueda se hace de izquierda a derecha, por lo que intentará siempre hacer coincidir el patrón desde la primera aparición de `>`.
La idea detrás de la expresión original si podría funcionar haciendo uso de una búsqueda hacia atrás, por ejemplo podemos instalar y usar el paquete [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex_exp = regex.compile(r"(?r)>(.*?\.pdf)")
>>> fo = "b---00b<do:YYYY>tftt_<fd>-<fd><ct><ct:MM>mmm.pdf"
>>> regex_exp.search(fo).groups()
('mmm.pdf',)
```

Su sintaxis es muy similar a la usada por `re` pero implementa algunas características no presentes en éste, por ejemplo permite la liberación del GIL  y con ello hacer uso de multithreading real.

Answer (score 0):

esto funciona:

> `match = re.search(r'([a-z0123456789]*\.pdf)', fo)
>   for g in match.groups():
>       print g`

Comment: Por favor agrega una descripción a tu respuesta. Lee **[Escribe a lo mejor de tu habilidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.